# Simple Bash script for proxychains

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I want to run the following command:

```
#! /bin/bash 
proxychains myApp —arg
```

If I put this into a Bash script it would start proxychains and myApp, but they are not linked to eachother! Proxychains then times out and traffic from myApp isn’t passed through the proxy.

The syntax is: proxychains program [args]

Edit: Just to clarify this: If I just type the command in an active console, it works. Same command in a bash script doesn’t work.

Comment: The proxychains.conf is fine. If I put „proxychains myApp —arg“ in the console everything works as expected. It’s just the bash script that isn’t working because it isn’t linking proxychains and myApp. It’s like the bash script is opening proxychains and myApp as two separate programs.

Comment: Just to clarify this: If I just type the command in an active console, it works. Same command in a bash script doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was running into the error I ran the script with sudo, because there were other parts in the script that depended on it.
Strangely it works fine if I run the proxychains part without sudo... Guess I somehow messed up the user permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the absolute path for both programs.

Comment: Doesn’t work either